# How to add sticker overlay to camera photo

Tags: ios, image, camera, overlay, photo

I'm trying to emulate what **[Celebrity Clicks](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/celebrity-clicks/id609442430?mt=8)** does: add a celebrity sticker to camera feed, position it and scale it, and than take the photo. This should give you a photo with the sticker applied, which is what Celebrity Click does. However, I'm having trouble merging the camera photo with the sticker. There are a few issues: the sticker scale and position is wrong when applied on the final camera image, because the image taken from the camera is actually much larger both in resolution and in size than the picture shown on the live camera feed when you set up the sticker.

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
[(GPUImageStillCamera *)videoCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:selectedFilter withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error) {
    selectedImage = [self imageByCombiningImage:processedImage withImage:celebOverlayView.imageView.image];
}];

- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {
UIImage *image = nil;
CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width),            MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize);
}
[firstImage drawInRect:cameraView.frame];

[firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2),
                                    roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))];
[secondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-secondImage.size.width)/2),
                                     roundf((newImageSize.height-secondImage.size.height)/2))];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

I have attached the before and after photo, so that you can see my problem.

Camera setup screen:
[image]

Photo taken with camera with the sticker applied:
[image]

I'm guessing that there is a better way to merge the two images or to simply apply the sticker at given coordinates to the camera captured image. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easiest if you save the relative frame of the added view in the picker and then compute the new frame when applying the added image combining the two images.

One of the many ways to do so is to divide all the parameters of the frame with the superview width and height respectively when taking the photo and then multiplying the same frame coordinates with the image width and height when trying to merge the two images.

Also for what you are doing I suggest you lose the core graphics to draw the image content and rather just use the image view: Crate the image view with the size of the background image, set the image then add another image view with the added image and set the frame as described above. Then simply create a screenshot of the view and your image is done. This way you will have no issues with scaling, transforms and such.

Comment: So you would suggest creating a view, which holds two imageviews: one with the image from the camera, and one with the sticker, and then just taking a context screenshot from that view?

Comment: Yes, but you only need 2 views, the background image view and the overlay image view. Taking this kind of screenshot does pretty much the same as you are doing in the background and is very handy for scaling, clipping and such. Just watch out to include the view content scale if needed.

Comment: So from which view would I take the screenshot? As you can see from the images above there are other elements on the screen at the time, so I can't just take the whole screen.

Comment: 1. create an image view with the size of the taken image and assign the taken image to it. 2. create an image view with the frame gotten with the procedure previously described and add it as a subview to the image view created in step one. 3. Assign the overlay image to the image view created in step two. 4. create a screenshot of the image view created in step one. Note: those views are nowhere visible as they are not in your view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Got it. I will give it a try.